# Collective term for those to which something applies

Tags: terminology, collective-nouns

If I have a certain 'condition', and that condition applies to a given grouping of people, is there a collective term to describe that group?

For example, I would say "These are the people to which 'X' applies..."; is there a way of saying "These people are 'X's <applicants>" (where 'applicants' here is incorrect, as they are not applying for X but are rather being categorised by it)?

EDIT: my use of the word 'condition' has thrown people off, I'm afraid. The context is actually in sorting data. If I set a filter of X, I am looking at one set of records (of people); a filter of Y will return another set. I am looking for a term to describe that set (other than 'set'!) if there is one.

Comment: It depends on the condition: "haemophiliacs come this way please, amputees over there." But "people with bruised arms" doesn't have a collective term, as far as I know.

Comment: @WeatherVane It's more about being in a particular group, than any shared attribute. i.e "'Label A' applies to X, Y, and Z" being translated to "X, Y, and Z are 'Label A's <something>"

Comment: Can you say what A, X, Y and Z are? It's a bit abstract, as if we have to guess what you are talking about, and my first guess was incorrect.

Comment: The word you want may well be *group*. "Haemophiliacs, amputees and concussion patients are in the 'Hospital' group on that bus; everyone else is in the 'Hard labour' group and will walk."

Comment: @WeatherVane - please see the edit to my question for clarification.

Comment: Maybe they are the ***affected group***.

Comment: The records may belong to a particular [**category**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/category).

Comment: Fellow sufferers / Americans / music-lovers / ....